# How can i draw a Snake path using GoogleMaps?

Tags: android, google-maps

That's How The Code Does It:

[image]

That's How I Want It

[image]

(1,2) "This Is What I Mean By Snake Trajectory The Other One Is"

This One Is Correct

[image]

Here I Want It To Be 3

[image]

(3,4) "I Want To Make It Draw Marker Correct Way
Example:

```
7 8 9
6 5 4
1 2 3
```

I Have Tried Changing The Variable I And J And Editing Them To Find My Needs But I Couldn't Make It Everyone Tells Me It's Simple But Can't Figure It Out

```java
for (double J = Lat1; J < Lat2; J += oneMeter) {

    for (double I = Lng1; I < Lng2-oneMeter; I += oneMeter) {
        if(I+oneMeter<=Lng2){
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title(markerNumber++ + "").position(new LatLng(J, I)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pvpanels)));
        //Test
        Polyline line = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().add(
                new LatLng(J, I),
                new LatLng(J, I+ oneMeter ))
                .width(10).color(Color.RED));}
        else if(I+oneMeter>Lng2){
            Polyline line = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().add(
                    new LatLng(J, I- oneMeter),
                    new LatLng(J+oneMeter , I))
                    .width(10).color(Color.RED));
        }

    }
}
```

I Expect It To Do Snake Shape And The Correct Points Format Image 1 Transfer To 2 And 3 Transfer To 4

Comment: double oneMeter = 0.000064; <<< Just Incase You Are Wondering

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear,
I am assuming that you have everything set-up and you're trying to connect to points in a Google Map with a path.

**Step 1.** add the following dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'

**Step 2.** in your map_activity.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

**Step 3.** in your MapsActivity.class

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {
private static final String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private Location mLastLocation;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private double latitudeValue = 0.0;
private double longitudeValue = 0.0;
private GoogleMap mMap;
private static final int PERMISSION_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
private List<LatLng> latLngList;
private MarkerOptions yourLocationMarker;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    latLngList = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }
    mLocationRequest = createLocationRequest();
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
    if(latLngList.size() > 0){
        refreshMap(mMap);
        latLngList.clear();
    }
    latLngList.add(latLng);
    Log.d(TAG, "Marker number " + latLngList.size());
    mMap.addMarker(yourLocationMarker);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
    LatLng defaultLocation = yourLocationMarker.getPosition();
    LatLng destinationLocation = latLng;
    //use Google Direction API to get the route between these Locations
    String directionApiPath = Helper.getUrl(String.valueOf(defaultLocation.latitude), String.valueOf(defaultLocation.longitude),
            String.valueOf(destinationLocation.latitude), String.valueOf(destinationLocation.longitude));
    Log.d(TAG, "Path " + directionApiPath);
    getDirectionFromDirectionApiServer(directionApiPath);
}
@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result = LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull LocationSettingsResult result) {
            final Status status = result.getStatus();
            switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Connection method has been called");
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
                        assignLocationValues(mLastLocation);
                        setDefaultMarkerOption(new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
                    }else{
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapsActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
                    }
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}
@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                // permission was denied, show alert to explain permission
                showPermissionAlert();
            }else{
                //permission is granted now start a background service
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
                    assignLocationValues(mLastLocation);
                    setDefaultMarkerOption(new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
private void assignLocationValues(Location currentLocation){
    if (currentLocation != null) {
        latitudeValue = currentLocation.getLatitude();
        longitudeValue = currentLocation.getLongitude();
        Log.d(TAG, "Latitude: " + latitudeValue + " Longitude: " + longitudeValue);
        markStartingLocationOnMap(mMap, new LatLng(latitudeValue, longitudeValue));
        addCameraToMap(new LatLng(latitudeValue, longitudeValue));
    }
}
private void addCameraToMap(LatLng latLng){
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(latLng)
            .zoom(16)
            .build();
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
}
private void showPermissionAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.permission_request_title);
    builder.setMessage(R.string.app_permission_notice);
    builder.create();
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MapsActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MapsActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapsActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, R.string.permission_refused, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
private void markStartingLocationOnMap(GoogleMap mapObject, LatLng location){
    mapObject.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("Current location"));
    mapObject.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(location));
}
private void refreshMap(GoogleMap mapInstance){
    mapInstance.clear();
}
protected LocationRequest createLocationRequest() {
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(5000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(3000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    return mLocationRequest;
}
private void setDefaultMarkerOption(LatLng location){
    if(yourLocationMarker == null){
        yourLocationMarker = new MarkerOptions();
    }
    yourLocationMarker.position(location);
}
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    super.onStart();
}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}
private void getDirectionFromDirectionApiServer(String url){
    GsonRequest<DirectionObject> serverRequest = new GsonRequest<DirectionObject>(
            Request.Method.GET,
            url,
            DirectionObject.class,
            createRequestSuccessListener(),
            createRequestErrorListener());
    serverRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            Helper.MY_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    VolleySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(serverRequest);
}
private Response.Listener<DirectionObject> createRequestSuccessListener() {
    return new Response.Listener<DirectionObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(DirectionObject response) {
            try {
                Log.d("JSON Response", response.toString());
                if(response.getStatus().equals("OK")){
                    List<LatLng> mDirections = getDirectionPolylines(response.getRoutes());
                    drawRouteOnMap(mMap, mDirections);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, R.string.server_error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
    };
}
private List<LatLng> getDirectionPolylines(List<RouteObject> routes){
    List<LatLng> directionList = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    for(RouteObject route : routes){
        List<LegsObject> legs = route.getLegs();
        for(LegsObject leg : legs){
            List<StepsObject> steps = leg.getSteps();
            for(StepsObject step : steps){
                PolylineObject polyline = step.getPolyline();
                String points = polyline.getPoints();
                List<LatLng> singlePolyline = decodePoly(points);
                for (LatLng direction : singlePolyline){
                    directionList.add(direction);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return directionList;
}
private Response.ErrorListener createRequestErrorListener() {
    return new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    };
}
private void drawRouteOnMap(GoogleMap map, List<LatLng> positions){
    PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true);
    options.addAll(positions);
    Polyline polyline = map.addPolyline(options);
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(new LatLng(positions.get(1).latitude, positions.get(1).longitude))
            .zoom(17)
            .build();
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
}
/**
 * Method to decode polyline points
 * Courtesy : http://jeffreysambells.com/2010/05/27/decoding-polylines-from-google-maps-direction-api-with-java
 * */
private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {
    List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<>();
    int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
    int lat = 0, lng = 0;
    while (index < len) {
        int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;
        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;
        LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                (((double) lng / 1E5)));
        poly.add(p);
    }
    return poly;
}
}
```

**RETURNED JSON RESPONSE OBJECT FROM GOOGLE DIRECTION API**

The returned response object is a Json object and the direction path is stored in the Polyline class. This is the class structure of the Json response object. We are going to use the Gson library to convert it to plain Java object class.

And should look something like this:

```
{
   "geocoded_waypoints" : [
      {
         "geocoder_status" : "OK",
         "place_id" : "ChIJZymwbofzU0YRvgugqrVwH8Q",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      },
      {
         "geocoder_status" : "OK",
         "place_id" : "EiJOeWdhdGFuIDMyLCAyNDIgMzEgSMO2cmJ5LCBTdmVyaWdl",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      }
   ],
   "routes" : [
      {
         "bounds" : {
            "northeast" : {
               "lat" : 55.8541564,
               "lng" : 13.661235
            },
            "southwest" : {
               "lat" : 55.85187149999999,
               "lng" : 13.660381
            }
         },
         "copyrights" : "Map data ©2016 Google",
         "legs" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "0.3 km",
                  "value" : 260
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "1 min",
                  "value" : 84
               },
               "end_address" : "Nygatan 32, 242 31 Hörby, Sweden",
               "end_location" : {
                  "lat" : 55.85187149999999,
                  "lng" : 13.660381
               },
               "start_address" : "Nygatan 12B, 242 31 Hörby, Sweden",
               "start_location" : {
                  "lat" : 55.8541564,
                  "lng" : 13.661235
               },
               "steps" : [
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0.3 km",
                        "value" : 260
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 min",
                        "value" : 84
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 55.85187149999999,
                        "lng" : 13.660381
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Head \u003cb\u003esouth\u003c/b\u003e on \u003cb\u003eNygatan\u003c/b\u003e toward \u003cb\u003eKvarngatan\u003c/b\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003eDestination will be on the left\u003c/div\u003e",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "o_|sIwekrAVHxBj@|Bh@nBr@d@Hb@L"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 55.8541564,
                        "lng" : 13.661235
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  }
               ],
               "traffic_speed_entry" : [],
               "via_waypoint" : []
            }
         ],
         "overview_polyline" : {
            "points" : "o_|sIwekrApCt@|Bh@nBr@hAV"
         },
         "summary" : "Nygatan",
         "warnings" : [],
         "waypoint_order" : []
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

**ENTITY OBJECT CLASSES**

We will create the following classes to mimic the structure of the Json response object. The classes are

Starting with **DIRECTIONOBJECT.JAVA**

```
public class DirectionObject {
    private List<RouteObject> routes;
    private String status;
    public DirectionObject(List<RouteObject> routes, String status) {
        this.routes = routes;
        this.status = status;
    }
    public List<RouteObject> getRoutes() {
        return routes;
    }
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
}
```

Next is **LEGSOBJECT.JAVA**

```
public class LegsObject {
    private List<StepsObject> steps;
    public LegsObject(List<StepsObject> steps) {
        this.steps = steps;
    }
    public List<StepsObject> getSteps() {
        return steps;
    }
}
```

Now the **POLYLINEOBJECT.JAVA**

```
public class PolylineObject {
    private String points;
    public PolylineObject(String points) {
        this.points = points;
    }
    public String getPoints() {
        return points;
    }
}
```

And the we create **ROUTEOBJECT.JAVA**

```
public class RouteObject {
    private List<LegsObject> legs;
    public RouteObject(List<LegsObject> legs) {
        this.legs = legs;
    }
    public List<LegsObject> getLegs() {
        return legs;
    }
}
```

We're almost there! now create the next class which is **STEPSOBJECTS.JAVA**

```
public class StepsObject {
    private PolylineObject polyline;
    public StepsObject(PolylineObject polyline) {
        this.polyline = polyline;
    }
    public PolylineObject getPolyline() {
        return polyline;
    }
}
```

After finishing setting up all of the classes above, now we move to setting up the network calls and API consumption!!

**We will be using Volley for Network calls**

Create this class:

```
public class CustomApplication extends Application{
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        requestQueue = 
VolleySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getRequestQueue();
    }
    public RequestQueue getVolleyRequestQueue(){
        return requestQueue;
    }
}
```

***Now the remaining classes are for the API consumption logic:***

Now create a class and name it **GsonRequest.java**

```
public class GsonRequest<T> extends Request<T> {
// create variables
private Gson mGson = new Gson();
private Class<T> tClass;
private Map<String, String> headers;
private Map<String, String> params;
private Response.Listener<T> listener;
public GsonRequest(int method, String url, Class<T> tClass, Response.Listener<T> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(method, url, errorListener);
    this.tClass = tClass;
    this.listener = listener;
    mGson = new Gson();
}
public GsonRequest(int method, String url, Class<T> tClass, Map<String, String> params, Response.Listener<T> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(method, url, errorListener);
    this.tClass = tClass;
    this.params = params;
    this.listener = listener;
    this.headers = null;
    mGson = new Gson();
}
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    return headers != null ? headers : super.getHeaders();
}
@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
    return params;
}
protected void deliverResponse(T response) {
    listener.onResponse(response);
}
@Override
protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    try {
        String json = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
        return Response.success(mGson.fromJson(json, tClass), HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    }
}
}
```

**VOLLEYSINGLETON.JAVA**

Create a new Java class and name it **VolleySingleton.java**

```
public class VolleySingleton {
private static VolleySingleton mInstance;
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
private static Context mCtx;
private VolleySingleton(Context context) {
    mCtx = context;
    mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();
    mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
        private final LruCache<String, Bitmap> cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);
        @Override
        public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
            return cache.get(url);
        }
        @Override
        public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
            cache.put(url, bitmap);
        }
    });
}
public static synchronized VolleySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new VolleySingleton(context);
    }
    return mInstance;
}
public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return mRequestQueue;
}
public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}
public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
    return mImageLoader;
}
}
```

**AND FINALLY**

**HELPER.JAVA**

Create another Java class name it **Helper.java**

```
public class Helper {
    private static final String DIRECTION_API = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=";
    public static final String API_KEY = "AIzaSyCuZCfoPPUV1upJT10kJbCbV71LUqwhFCM";
    public static final int MY_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS = 5000;
    public static String getUrl(String originLat, String originLon, String destinationLat, String destinationLon){
        return Helper.DIRECTION_API + originLat+","+originLon+"&destination="+destinationLat+","+destinationLon+"&key="+API_KEY;
    }
    public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm for me! I hope it does work for the question poster